# Insert bulk failed due to a schema change of the target table in adf

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

Hi i am using ADF to load the parquet files into a sql server. there were 15 files i have load to SQl. Out of 15, 14 has stored into SQL for one file i am getting an error.
Insert bulk failed due to a schema change of the target table. Do you know the reasons

Comment: The error is telling you the reason.

Comment: But the schema is not changedI have checked.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please modify the data flow on the Source and the Sink to allow [Schema Drift](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-schema-drift)? Maybe this helps you avoid the error.

On the Source:

- On the Source Settings tab: Make sure "Allow schema drift" is checked
  and "Validate schema" is unchecked.
- Make a check on "Infer drifted column types".

On the Sink:

- Make sure "Allow schema drift" is checked and "Validate schema" is unchecked.
- On the Settings tab, change "Table action" to "Recreate table". This should infer the new schema and drop and create the columns based on what it finds.
- On the Mappings tab: make sure "Auto Mapping" is enabled

[image]